# How to convert QueryDict to python dictionary

Tags: django, dojo

I am trying to post some data from Dojo to Django application. I use postData to post the data to the server
here is the code snippet

```
var csrftokenval    =   dojo.cookie('csrftoken'); 
    var selectedmoid1   =   tree.getSelectedItemId();
    var loadURL         =   '/calerts/';
    dojo.rawXhrPost({
        url     :   loadURL,
        headers :   {'X-CSRFToken':csrftokenval},
        postData:   dojo.toJson({'selectedmoid':selectedmoid1,'previousval':previousVal}),
        handleAs:   "text",
        load    :   function(data, ioArgs){
            dojo.byId('content-main').innerHTML =   data;
        },
        error   :   function(data, ioArgs){
        }
    });
```

In the Django views i get the data as

```
def calerts(request):
user        =   request.user
compId      =   int(request.session.get('USERCOMPANY_ID','-1'))
listCount   =   25
print '0000000000000000000000000000000 ',request.POST
print 'post dictionary ::: ',request.POST.dict()
```

I know to get the dict value from querydict using dict() method however in my case the print is

> post dictionary :::  {u'{"selectedmoid":"4","previousval":"4"}': u''}

i dont undersand where that final u'' comes from. Also i would like to retrieve the values of selectedmoid and previousval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sending the data as a raw JSON post, not a form-encoded one. So you should access `request.body`, not `request.POST`, and decode the JSON from there.